# Why I lost my 'question'?

Tags: support, questions, closed-questions, deleted-questions

I have posted a question regarding cockney some while ago. As a learner, I always need the history of my posts, including the answers and responses so I can make sort of review about my progress.  Now, as I can't find it anymore, could admins help me to give it back? May I ask politely why that question has disappeared?

Answer (score 6):

The question is located at https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/128000/cockney-how-should-i-know-more-about-it. It was automatically deleted because it met [the following criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/89334):

> **If the question was closed more than `9` days ago, and ...**
>
> - not closed as a duplicate
> - has a score of 0 or less
> - is not locked
> - has no answers with a score > 0
> - has no accepted answer
> - has no pending reopen votes
> - has not been edited in the past `9` days
>
> .. it will be automatically deleted